# CUDA shared array not getting values?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to implement simple parallel reduction. I am using the code from the CUDA SDK. But somehow there is a problem in my kernel as the shared array is not getting values of the global array and its all zeroes.

```
extern __ shared __ float4 sdata[];

// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem

unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

sdata[tid] = dev_src[i];

__syncthreads();

// do reduction in shared mem

for(unsigned int s = 1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2) {
    if(tid % (2*s) == 0){
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    }
    __syncthreads();
}

// write result for this block to global mem
if(tid == 0)
    out[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
```

**Edit**:

Ok I got it working by removing the `extern` keyword and making the shared array a constant size like `512`. I am in good shape now. Maybe someone can explain why it was not working with the `extern` keyword.

Comment: so dev_src has the correct values but sdata somehow is not getting dev_src values

Comment: Don't add updates to the comments. Update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know why this is happening as I have faced this before. How are you launching the kernel?

Remember in the launch `kernel<<<blocks,threads,sharedMemory>>>` the `sharedMemory` should be the size of the shared memory in bytes. So, if you are declaring for 512 elements, the third parameter should be `512 * sizeof(float4)`. I think you are just calling as below, which is wrong

```
kernel<<<blocks,threads,512>>>   // this is wrong
```

Comment: To clarify this answer, since it is mostly correct: if you specify a __shared__ variable as `extern __shared__" then you must specify the amount of shared memory (in bytes) to allocate at kernel launch using the third parameter of the execution configuration (the <<<>>>), as Programmer describes.